# How to prompt a message before installing Android App

Tags: android

I want to prompt a message with YES and NO buttons before installing an App.
Suppose if I have an App "MyWorld" installed in my phone and I want to install its latest version, So on installing, I want to prompt a message "MyWorld App of version 1.1.2 is already installed, Do you want to install its latest version 1.1.3?". If user clicks on yes button, latest App should start installing else installation is terminated.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Who initiates the update?  Does your app download the update?

Comment: I am assuming you are manually downloading and installing the app from a private server. But what have you tried?

Comment: @DegenSharew yes.. I haven't tried anything yet, I don't know how to start.. :/

Comment: well start it it is very easy. To give you a hint. First check the version of the app on the remote server, if it is higher than the one installed download it ( the apk file) then show the prompt after that follow this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically